# Birrational regular morphism to $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:C\to\mathbb{P}^1$ be a regular morphism of projective algebraic curves which is birrational. Is $f$ necessarily an isomorphism?

Comment: What if $C = \mathbb A^1$ and $f$ sends $t \mapsto [1 : t]$?

Comment: oh sorry $C$ is projective

Comment: Do you know that every rational map from a smooth curve to a projective variety is a morphism? (Hartshorne I 6.8)

Comment: The answer is yes.